# How to join the Five more tables in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to join the below tables to get result like in "Result" table:

Table: Invoice

```
Inv_No  Fk_Rep_ID   Inv_Date    Inv_Amt
3000         202    10/1/2014   35
3001         194    11/1/2014   40
```

Table :Return

```
Return_ID   FK_Rep_ID   Ret_Date    Ret_Amt
2000             202    15/1/2014   67
```

Table: Credit_ Note

```
Note_ID FK_Rep_ID   Note_Date   Note_Amnt
1000        NULL    4/2/2014    12
```

Table:Receipt_Items

```
Fk_Rec_No   FK_Item_No  Item_Type
7788            1000    0
7788            2000    1
7788            3000    2
7788            3001    2
```

Table :Sales_Rep

```
Rep_ID  Rep_Name
180      Vinu
194      Bibin
202      Salman
```

Result

```
Fk_Rec_No   Fk_Item_No  Item_Type   Rep_Name    Item_Date   Item_Amt
7788            1000    Credit_ Note    NULL    4/2/2014    12
7788            2000    Return          salman  15/1/2014   67
7788            3000    Invoice         salman  10/1/2014   35
7788            3001    Invoice         Bibin   11/1/2014   40
```

Please have a look at my query:

```
SELECT tt.*,SR.Rep_Name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        fk_receipt_no
        ,fk_item_no
        ,CASE Item_type 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Credit Note'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Return'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Invoice'
        END as ITEM_type,
        Case Item_type when 2 then '-'+Cast(Item_Amnt as varchar(50))
                        else Cast(Item_Amnt as varchar(50)) End Item_Amnt
        ,COALESCE(R.FK_Rep_ID,C.FK_Rep_ID,I.FK_Rep_ID)  as FK_Rep_ID
        ,COALESCE(R.Ret_Date,C.Note_Date,I.Inv_Date)  as Item_Date
    FROM Recp_Item RI
    LEFT JOIN [Return] R ON RI.FK_Item_no=R.Return_ID
    LEFT JOIN Credit_Note C ON RI.FK_Item_No=C.Note_ID
    LEFT JOIN Invoice I ON RI.FK_Item_No=I.Inv_No
) tt
LEFT JOIN [Sales Rep] SR ON SR.Rep_ID=tt.FK_Rep_ID
WHERE tt.FK_Receipt_No='7188'
```

Comment: @Salman where is the query ?

Comment: I need to take "Item_Amt" from specific tables , here i am taken from table "Receipt_Items"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ri.Fk_Rec_No   
      ,ri.FK_Item_No  
      ,A.Item_Type
      ,sr.Rep_Name
      ,A.Inv_Date AS Item_Date
      ,A.Inv_Amt  AS Item_Amt
FROM (
SELECT Inv_No   , 'Invoice' AS Item_Type, Fk_Rep_ID, Inv_Date, Inv_Amt FROM dbo.Invoice
UNION ALL
SELECT Return_ID, 'Return' AS Item_Type, Fk_Rep_ID, Ret_Date, Ret_Amt FROM dbo.[Return]
UNION ALL 
SELECT Note_ID  , 'Credit_ Note' AS Item_Type, Fk_Rep_ID, Note_Date, Note_Amnt FROM dbo.Credit_ Note
 ) A
LEFT JOIN Receipt_Items ri  ON ri.FK_Item_No  = A.Inv_No
LEFT JOIN Sales_Rep sr      ON sr.Rep_ID = A.Fk_Rep_ID
```

**Note**

I think you need to look into your database schema, As I think these three tables are unnecessary you should really have Only one table with one extra column to identify which record is an Invoice, Return or Credit note. Your current schema violates basic rules of Database normalisation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction mr. Ali, If i want to add "-" (minus) sign for retun and credit note , how it will be ? eg: -67  & -12

Comment: No problem, to add a minus sign simply do `SELECT '-' + CAST(Note_ID AS VARCHAR(100))`, also please accept the answer if it helped you thank you.